# App Transport Security settings for private framework

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks, app-transport-security

I'm making a private framework for third party developers, who do not need to know anything about servers, `URLs` and so on.
I need to make some settings for `ATS`, but it seems like changing `info.plist` in that framework's project doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong or it's supposed to be like this, that I must not manage `ATS` in scope of my framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ATS configuration applies to the final app, not any particular framework in it, so the info.plist that will be used will be part of the project that *uses* your framework.

It is up to the developers responsible for *that* project to add the appropriate keys to their info.plist. There is nothing you can do as the framework developer aside from documenting any required ATS configuration.

Comment: ok, thanks for this comment. That means, I need to convince backend developers to make the server to satisfy Apple's requirements..

Comment: While adopting secure transport is to be encouraged (and this is why Apple has enabled ATS in iOS 9) it is not required by Apple. Disabling ATS is legitimate.

Comment: nevertheless this will be up to framework's users to disable is, so it's not a case

Answer (score -1):

Opened my Projects `info.plist` file

Add a Key called `NSAppTransportSecurity` as a `Dictionary`.

Added a Subkey called `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as `Boolean` and set its value to **YES**.

then your every url will be accepted.

Comment: But will your app be accepted on the app store? You just circumvented an important security feature. You better have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: There are no issues with disabling ATS and app store approval.

Comment: yes this is on developer.... if app is only made for ios 9 then it must that you use ATS but if your app support ios 8 or older.. then u can simply disable this feature... there will be no issue in app approval